# How to use CFStreamCreatePairWithSocket using CFSocketNativeHandle

Tags: sockets, ssl, xmpp, swift3

I am trying to write socket for XMPP, after connection is established socket should reestablish connection with updated TLS settings. Problem is delegate methods Stream.Event.openCompleted is called on both outputStream and inputStream but Stream.Event.hasSpaceAvailable is not getting called after CFStreamCreatePairWithSocket.

code:-

```
if tls{

var readStream :Unmanaged<CFReadStream>?
var writeStream:Unmanaged<CFWriteStream>?
reset()

print("establish tls ")
tlsEnabled = true


let socketData = CFWriteStreamCopyProperty(self.outputStream as CFWriteStream,
                                           CFStreamPropertyKey.socketNativeHandle) as! CFData


let native = CFSocketNativeHandle(CFDataGetBytePtr(socketData).pointee)




inputStream.close()
outputStream.close()

inputStream.remove(from: RunLoop.current, forMode: .defaultRunLoopMode)
outputStream.remove(from: RunLoop.current, forMode: .defaultRunLoopMode)
inputStream = nil
outputStream = nil




CFStreamCreatePairWithSocket(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                             native,
                             &readStream,
                             &writeStream)




inStream             = readStream!.takeRetainedValue()
outStream            = writeStream!.takeRetainedValue()

inStream.delegate    = self
outStream.delegate   = self

inStream.setProperty(kCFBooleanTrue, forKey: kCFStreamPropertyShouldCloseNativeSocket as Stream.PropertyKey)
outStream.setProperty(kCFBooleanTrue, forKey: kCFStreamPropertyShouldCloseNativeSocket as Stream.PropertyKey)

inStream.setProperty(StreamSocketSecurityLevel.negotiatedSSL as AnyObject,
                     forKey: Stream.PropertyKey.socketSecurityLevelKey)
outStream.setProperty(StreamSocketSecurityLevel.negotiatedSSL as AnyObject,
                      forKey: Stream.PropertyKey.socketSecurityLevelKey)

let settings: [NSObject: NSObject] = [kCFStreamSSLValidatesCertificateChain: NSNumber(value: false),
                                      kCFStreamSSLPeerName: kCFNull]
inStream.setProperty(settings,
                     forKey: kCFStreamPropertySSLSettings as Stream.PropertyKey)
outStream.setProperty(settings,
                      forKey: kCFStreamPropertySSLSettings as Stream.PropertyKey)


inStream.schedule(in: RunLoop.current, forMode:.defaultRunLoopMode)
outStream.schedule(in:RunLoop.current, forMode:.defaultRunLoopMode)

inStream.open()
outStream.open()
```

}

Answer (score 2):

The issue seems to be with creating the socket using CFSocket instead of creating the native socket handle directly.

Modifying your code to create the socket directly using `socket(_:_:_)` instead of using CFSocket and CFSocketNativeHandle results in the stream delegate methods being called for me.

```
/** 
 Create sockaddr_in (IPV4) address for google.com
 Note: If you need to resolve DNS for a hostname, use CFHost
 */
var remoteaddress = sockaddr_in()
inet_pton(PF_INET, 
          "207.47.131.217".cString(using: .utf8),
          &sockaddress.sin_addr)
sockaddress.sin_port = UInt16(443).bigEndian
sockaddress.sin_family = sa_family_t(AF_INET)
// Create native socket handle, if sockhandle < 0, error occurred, (check errno)
let sockhandle = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP)
// if connectStatus < 0, error occurred (check errno)
let connectStatus = connect(sockhandle, 
                            &remoteaddress, 
                            socklen_t(MemoryLayout<sockaddr_in>.size))

var readStream :Unmanaged<CFReadStream>?
var writeStream:Unmanaged<CFWriteStream>?
CFStreamCreatePairWithSocket(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                             sockhandle,
                             &readStream, &writeStream)
```